# Get .env variable inside object in the controller NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I created .env

```
APP_PORT=3001
DEST=C:\data\formations
```

I have configService:ConfigService in the controller contractor. I want to get `DEST` for destination from .env in this code.

```js
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: /*here*/ ,
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const filename: string = path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(/\s/g, '')
      const extension: string = path.parse(file.originalname).ext
      cb(null, `${filename}${extension}`)
    }
  })
}))
```

When I use this inside this other object I get an error.

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ConfigModule` for getting the environment varible.

Check the document: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Comment: i did the problem here is the edithor refuse this.configServise I think because it is another object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use configuration outside Nest's IoC container, you can try [nest-typed-config](https://github.com/Nikaple/nest-typed-config#using-config-outside-nests-ioc-container-usage-in-decorators):

```js
import { selectConfig } from 'nest-typed-config';
import { ConfigModule, FileConfig } from '@/module/config';

const fileConfig = selectConfig(ConfigModule, FileConfig);

@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: fileConfig.destination,
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const filename: string = path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(/\s/g, '')
      const extension: string = path.parse(file.originalname).ext
      cb(null, `${filename}${extension}`)
    }
  })
}))
```